# Notepad++ replace n characters in a certain pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++

In Notepad++ version 6.7.8.2, I would like to replace the string

```
<p class=question><b>nn.</b>
```

where nn is any charachter 1-20000. (followed by a .)

I've tried expressions, etc. but can't get it to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Sorry forgot to show what I've tried so far:

```
<p class=question><b>[\..]</b>
```

Comment: What do you want to replace with what?

Comment: Please, show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

Find what:  `<p class=question><b>\b([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|1[0-9]{4}|20000)\b\.</b>`

Replace with:  `Something Else`

`\b([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,3}|1[0-9]{4}|20000)\b` should match the range from 1 to 20000.

Comment: Thanks. That did it just fine. @Mechan - that worked for the first 9 items only. Double digits weren't replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expression:

```
<p class=question><b>([0-9]+)\.</b>
```

Replace for example with:

```
Question \1:
```